# How do i load an image with ajax/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to load an image, that is generated by a PHP script. The PHP script accepts a three dimensional array as a parameter and creates from it an image. How do i pass the arguments with ajax? How do i load the image?

Comment: How does it accept it, Via post/get correct? If so, post data to it in the same format. A little more detail would help in answering this...

Comment: Ajax does not load binary data into a page.

If you use the DATA-URI scheme, you can however return a B64 encoded stream.

What do you mean by "accepts a 3D array"

Comment: @mplungjan, one could just send back normal URLs to images, stored on the server, since they are loaded asynchronously anyway.

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL and its parameter(s)?

Comment: @Kat, then he would need to STORE them first since they are generated from the request. Ajax can run synchronously too.

Comment: @mplungjan -- I don't see any reason to believe that what you said is true.

Comment: @MAl Strange comment. You make an ajax request for an image, how would that image be returned in the reply? You could get either a string representation of the image (data uri) or a link to where the server had stored the image so you could make an image tag that would request the binary data... that is how http works

Comment: @mplungjan  - I interpreted your statement "he would need to STORE them first since they are generated from the request" as "he would need to store the images first, since they are generated from the page request."  I thought that's what you meant and I don't think that's true.\

Comment: @MAL I did. Page makes request for image using Ajax, server can EITHER return B64 or a LINK to where the image has been generated right now based on the parms sent to the server. If the server does not return B64 encoded image data, a separate http request has to be made to load the image from the server - ok, perhaps returned from memory but more likely from disk.

Comment: @mplungjan -- that is a very bad design!  Do not do that!  Web servers should be stateless.  The result of the page request should include a link that encodes all the information needed for a completely separate program to generate the image.

Comment: @Mal - I am not ADVOCATING that design - I am saying this is what the user needs to do to make HIS version work.

Comment: @Malvolio let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2599/discussion-between-mplungjan-and-malvolio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way (barring some really hairy `<canvas>` tag magic) to move data from Javascript into an image, but fortunately, you don't have to.  All you have to do generate the URL for the PHP script and assign it to an Image and boom.

```
var img = new Image();
var img.src = "http://phphost.net/imagegenerate.php?array=3,1,2,3,21,1"; // or whatever
```

Comment: `new Image()` is new for me. It works in Chrome, but does it also work in other browsers like IE6 or IE7? If not, I'd recommend `document.createElement('img')` instead.

Comment: It is ancient and should work in all browsers. Too bad I did not suggest this. I was sure we needed to solve the 3D array first

Comment: I believe `new Image()` pre-dates `document.createElement` by several years.

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar but using ASPX rather than PHP, I used query string params to generate the image, and jQuery to load the image into an existing  object in the document:

```
var chartRootURL = 'http://127.0.0.1/';
var chartQueryParameters = 'inst=APPL&w=900&h=200';
var url = chartRootURL + 'chartImage.aspx?' + chartQueryParameters +
                    '&ts=' + new Date().getMilliseconds();

var img = $('#chartimg').attr('src', url)
                    .load(function (response, status) {
                        $('#chartimg').show();
                    });
```

Comment: Ahem - is that not just generating the url on the server instead of on the client?

Comment: No, both lines are javascript and executed on the client, the variable chartQueryParameters is built up to include things like width, height, requested instrument, studies etc, all constructed on the client side.  I'll add an additional line to my sample to be clearer.

Answer (score -2):

How about

```
document.write("<img src='http://www.aurl.com/generator.php?" + yourParams + "' alt='exciting image here' />")
```

Comment: VERY poor and inflexible idea. At least use $("#someContainer").append("<img />")....